# Ember.js outlet's model change but the content not change

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my user controller,i use a outlet to render userLog section,and use controllerFor('userLog').set('model',App.UserLog.find(model.id)) to set the model of userLog,but i want to add a button to userLog section ,when user click it,it will load more logs,but i tried to push new object to its model,nothing happened.

here is the project address:https://bitbucket.org/magicshui/web/src/4ff895b5c22823c6ec1c1536ca2e7b59237f0459/assets/coffee/app/routes/?at=master

when you goto web/index.html#/users and then click one user name,it will show the section,because i haven't set all url correctly,so you should fill into the address bar this address directly.

the problem file is user.coffee and userLog.coffee

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be using `pushObject` instead of `push` that's how Ember catches that you've changed the array and updates the template